# Sonar scanner analysis hangs out on util.lang.ConcreteReceiverGuard

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am running a sonar analysis of a java project with sonar-java and the following configuration:

```
SonarQuber Servcer 5.6
Sonar-java 4.10.0.10260
SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778
Java 1.8.0_121 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
```

When I start a sonar analysis it seems to be working until I got the following logs and then the analysis simply continues to run forever (last time it ran all night long):

```
util.lang.ConcreteReceiverGuard reports a runtime deprecation: calling method "padl.kernel.impl.CodeLevelModel.create()" from class "it.unibz.sonarqube_plugin.ExampleSensor"
Please use the methods in "padl.generator.helper.ModelGenerator" to obtain code-level models.
```

How can I see what is going wrong and how to fix it?

I should note that:

- Several projects use the same server and the same rules, they have the same message but the analysis continues.
- Even if I run `sonar-scanner -X` with the debug flag I don't get more messages.

If needed the full log of the analysis is here (note that the issue also appear when the analysis is started by a jenkins post job task):

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: XXX\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: XXX\sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778
INFO: Java 1.8.0_121 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
INFO: User cache: XXX\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load global repositories
INFO: Load global repositories (done) | time=102ms
INFO: User cache: XXX\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=6ms
INFO: SonarQube server 5.6
INFO: Default locale: "fr_FR", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=112ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=16ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=153ms
INFO: Publish mode
INFO: -------------  Scan Pricing - Serveur
INFO: Load server rules
INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=84ms
INFO: Base dir: XXX\server
INFO: Working dir: XXX\server\.scannerwork
INFO: Source paths: src
INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: fr_FR
INFO: Index files
INFO: Excluded sources: 
INFO:   src/main/js/node_modules/**
INFO:   src/main/webapp/**
INFO: 584 files indexed
INFO: 230 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
INFO: Quality profile for java: XXX Java
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=77ms
INFO: Sensor JavaSquidSensor
INFO: Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 7
INFO: JavaClasspath initialization
INFO: JavaClasspath initialization (done) | time=6ms
INFO: JavaTestClasspath initialization
INFO: JavaTestClasspath initialization (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Java Main Files AST scan
INFO: 584 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 213/584 files analyzed, current file: XXX\XXX.java
INFO: 255/584 files analyzed, current file: XXX\XXX.java
INFO: 473/584 files analyzed, current file: XXX\XXX.java
INFO: Java Main Files AST scan (done) | time=35221ms
INFO: 584/584 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Java Test Files AST scan
INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Java Test Files AST scan (done) | time=0ms
INFO: 0/0 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor JavaSquidSensor (done) | time=35823ms
INFO: Sensor ExampleSensor
INFO: BaseDir----->XXX\server
Analysing Test...
util.lang.ConcreteReceiverGuard reports a runtime deprecation: calling method "padl.kernel.impl.CodeLevelModel.create()" from class "it.unibz.sonarqube_plugin.ExampleSensor"
Please use the methods in "padl.generator.helper.ModelGenerator" to obtain code-level models.
```

Comment: You seem to have custom plugins in your instance. Try removing them (with a server restart) and re-analyzing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis fails during execution of `Sensor ExampleSensor`. This analysis step is provided by one of the plugins installed on the SonarQube server (apparently `it.unibz.sonarqube_plugin.ExampleSensor`).

You need to contact the maintainers of this (potentially proprietary) plugin and submit this to them (can be a bug). Or at the very least share this context with your SonarQube admin (in case there is no intent to have an *Example*Sensor affect real-life projects).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try to see with the admin what is this plugin.